# How can I use Mootools with Drupal 6?

Tags: 6, javascript

I am looking for a way to use Mootools with Drupal 6, without disabling jQuery, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to load JQuery in "noConflict mode" or MooTools in "Dollar Safe mode"; your best bet is to use "Dollar Safe mode" to avoid effecting Drupal.

See [MooTools, Framework Compatibility, and Dollar $afe Mode](http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-dollar-safe-mode), and [The Dollar Safe Mode](http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode/).